# Why is a link error reported when using freetype-rs?

Tags: rust, freetype

I have a basic project that uses freetype-rs, but it reports a link error when I run `cargo run`. My system is OS X Yosemite 10.10.2.

**Directory listing**

```
./Cargo.toml
./src/main.rs
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]

name = "usefree"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["zhch <zhch@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
freetype-rs = "0.1.0"
```

**src/main.rs**

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate freetype;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello,World!");
}
```

**Error from `cargo run`**

```
Compiling usefree v0.0.1 (file:///Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
note: "cc" "-m64" "-L" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/usefree.o" "-o" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/usefree" "-Wl,-force_load,/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libmorestack.a" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/deps/libfreetype-4323fafa5d970f54.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/deps/libfreetype_sys-a42cc5659b21e38e.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/deps/liblibc-ef5cbad4ef5c7a1e.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-dd68b8369bcd8ff0.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-74fa456f.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcollections-74fa456f.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_unicode-74fa456f.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librand-74fa456f.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-74fa456f.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-74fa456f.rlib" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-74fa456f.rlib" "-L" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug" "-L" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/Users/zhangcheng/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "-L" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/.rust/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin" "-L" "/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin" "-l" "freetype" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-l" "System" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../../../../../.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "-l" "compiler-rt"
note: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/.rust/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin'
ld: library not found for -lfreetype
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `usefree`.
```

After `brew install freetype`, rust compiles freetype but the error still there.

```
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
   Compiling libc v0.1.8
   Compiling bitflags v0.1.1
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.5
   Compiling libz-sys v0.1.6
   Compiling freetype-sys v0.1.2
   Compiling freetype-rs v0.1.0
   Compiling usefree v0.0.1 (file:///Users/zhangcheng/temp/d3/san)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it builds a Rust library which wants to link with freetype but there is no such library on your system. Since you're using Mac OS X, it is not really unexpected. Freetype is native to Linux world, not for macs.

You need to install freetype, for example, with brew:

```
brew install freetype
```

It would install the library to `/usr/local/lib`.

If you do use brew, it would automatically add a corresponding pkg-config configuration to your system, and because `freetype-sys` (a dependency of `freetype-rs`) uses pkg-config to discover the library, everything will start working automatically.

If you're not using brew, chances are you won't get a pkg-config configuration, and no necessary flags would be added to the build automatically. Frankly, I don't know how to overcome this without changing `freetype-sys` build to explicitly add `/usr/local/lib` (or whatever path the library is installed into). You can add a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) to your program which would append the path to freetype to the build options, but it won't affect the compilation of dependency. It may or may not work.

Comment: @Matveen   I do use brew, but after I installed freetype, the error still there. I clear the project then run `cargo run` again, the rust compile freetype again. Maybe rust didn't use the freetype which brew installed?

Comment: That's strange, because I've also checked it on my Mac and it did work. Do you have pkg-config installed? Unfortunately, I don't remember whether it should come from brew as well or if it is built-in, and I can't check until tomorrow. Try running `pkg-config --libs freetype2`. It should show something like `-L /usr/local/Cellar/.../ -lfreetype`. If it doesn't, then it is likely some issue with pkg-config configuration files.

Comment: I ran the project on Linux, it reports the same error. and pkg-config tells it can't find freetype or freetype2, I'll learn more about pkg-config, thanks

Comment: on OSX pkg-config was not built-in, after installing pkg-config, everything goes well.

Comment: @Malloc i am encountering similar issues, but `brew install pkg-config` did not fix things for me.  Is that how you installed `pkg-config`, or did you take additional steps?

Comment: (ah, I had to delete the `target/` directory after installing `pkg-config` to force some of the dependencies to get recompiled... that is unfortunate (and a tiny bit surprising to me; i clearly have not digested how much info is stored in `target/` from run-to-run), but i do not know if there is a good way around that ...)